# Does the method "session.createSQLQuery()" have a memory leak? How to resolve it?

Tags: java, hibernate

My application has a memory leak problem, so I used JProfiler to find the cause. I found that the problem is caused by native sql in Hibernate when using `session.createSQLQuery()`.

Does anyone else have the same problem? How to resolve the problem? I have to use native SQL in Hibernate because HQL doesn't meet my requirements.

The leaked class is `HashMap`, which the root cause is `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.selectexpressionimpl` alike. I found it's used in `createSQLQuery()` method.

For my table name is varied(200+ table), it's unable to create a POJO for every table, so I need to use native SQL in Hibernate. What should I do? Any ideas?

I put some code here:

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                String sql = (String) list.get(i);

                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
                query.setParameter(0, new Date());
                query.setParameter(1, new Date());
                //query.setParameter(2, format.format(new Date()));
                query.executeUpdate();
            }

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            b = true;
```

and my inspection in JProfiler shows the memory leak:

[image]

I found the memory leak happens in insert/update SQL query, not in select query.

Comment: post some code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is due to unusable keys being added in QueryPlanCache.
This issue has been fixed in newer hibernate versions.

More details are provided in this jira ticket : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-4579

Comment: thank you for answer. But my hibernate version is 5.2.17, seems it's fixed in this version, why it's still there?

Comment: Use recent version Hibernate can avoid this problem.